# Flutter: How to customize Firebase reset password email

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to send a 6 digits PIN code to the user's email instead of a link, and the user should change the password somehow in the app if that the PIN match the other in the email, is this possible ? if yes How? and do I need a website for this?

Comment: does this answer your question https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#web-version-9_1

Comment: I tried that already but I did not understand how to implement it.

Comment: There's nothing Flutter specific about this, and the (limited) possibilities have been covered before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+How+to+customize+Firebase+reset+password+email. If you're tried something that should be possible, but can't get it to work, edit your question to show what you tried.